# is there other way of sending email on localhost, without starting apache on xampp

Tags: apache, iis, smtp

my phpmailer works fine on xampp because Mysql & Apache  are started , when I upload the website to IIS its  not sending email because on  APache service is not being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure SMTP E-Mail in IIS:

open iis manager. select your site.

Features View, double-click SMTP E-mail.

On the SMTP E-mail page, type the e-mail address of the sender in the E-mail address text box.

On the SMTP E-mail page, select any delivery method.

Deliver e-mail to SMTP server:

[image]

Click Apply in the Actions pane.

set below setting in the php.ini file:

```
[mail function]
SMTP=localhost
sendmail_from = sender mail address
smtp_port=25
```

Comment: thank you I found out the messages were waiting in the in the problem was the network administrator blocking me

Comment: @Zlatan I request you to mark the helpful solution as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issue.